# How can I check in protocol A's extension, that whether or not `self` follows protocol B?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Design patterns looks something like this:

```
protocol Base {

}

protocol A: Base {

}

protocol B: Base {

}

extension A {
    func someFunc() {
        if ((self as Any) is any B.Type) { // <- apparently this compiles, but doesn't return True as it's designed in extension A, not the real class that both follows A and B
            print("So it also follows protocol B")
        }
    }
}

class finalClass: A, B {
    func anotherFunc() {
        someFunc()
    }
}
```

I'd like to check in definition of extension A, whether or not the class calling that function, also follows protocol B?

I release that using `as?` could work, but is there a certain pattern or best practice here?

Comment: `extension A: where Self: B` doesn't really work as it doesn't overload the function, and I need `someFunc()` to work whether or not Self follows B...

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating this - how about simply `self is B`?

Comment: Protocols without any requirements are pointless. The goal of Swift protocols is that the compiler can complain at **compile time** if one of the properties/methods is not implemented.

Comment: What do you mean by "as it doesn't overload the function"? You can definitely declare `someFunc` in both an `extension A where Self: B`, and a plain `extension A`.

Comment: @vadian [Protocols are more than Bags of Syntax](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/). Protocols without any requirements are not necessarily "pointless".

Comment: @Sweeper If you explicitly want to check for the implementation of a method they are.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes I could overload the function, but calling `finalClass.someFunc()` doesn't call the overloaded function, but only functions defined at `extension A`. so it's basically not working for me

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm just straight up using `as?` it's much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to define "doesn't really work". Other people see it working and don't understand.

```swift
extension A {
  func someFunc() -> String { "A" }
}

extension A where Self: B {
  func someFunc() -> String { "B" }
}

final class AClass: A { }
final class ABClass: A & B { }

AClass().someFunc() // "A"
ABClass().someFunc() // "B"
```

Comment: I marked the class as `ABClass: A, B` not `ABClass:A & B`.... changing it does fix the problem, thx; https://github.com/Life-USTC/Life-USTC/commit/184f9d7d45d7e53a8bd400762b5730693d6065ac#diff-ee8c91721ad2e50c835f6953ac78d476e15b83244920c923bf966830237d3b06